# How to retrieve data from a database efficiently?

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm building an android app, and I need to retrieve a list of users from a database. I know how to write the query. I will have back a list of object.

I was wondering how to do this in an efficient way considering that I need that list in 3 activities. I think that repeating the same code for 3 times, in 3 different activities is not optimal.

Thanks

Comment: in your DB helper class write a function to retrieve list of users. then use it from anywhere you need

Comment: It's an external database. I will make the query through internet.

Comment: You write the query using JDBC: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Comment: if you need the same in three different Activities, maybe you just need only one Activity ?

Comment: It may be a solution, but I still prefer to have 3 different activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you comment you are fetching this user data from server,
you can consider following:

1. make a web service to retrieve user list.
2. call the web service first time you need list of users.
3. cache this list in shared preferences or SQLite DB, depending upon size of list.
4. use it where ever you need.
5. refresh your list from server periodically or as per your need.

Comment: Ok, I could cache it in shared preferences. From where? From the first activity that requires it? From an application activity?

Comment: yes, make a server call first time you need it. updated answer